# how can I modify one column of current and next record depending of some criteria?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Having DDL

```
CREATE TABLE #ServiceChange(
    [ID] [int] identity(1,1),
    [comp] [char](2) NOT NULL,
    [date] [numeric](8, 0) NOT NULL,
    [custid] [numeric](7, 0) NOT NULL,
    [service] [char](35) NOT NULL,
    [type] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [amount] [numeric](9, 2) NOT NULL,
    [custname] [char](30) NOT NULL,
    [GROUPID] [char](2) NULL
)
```

And original and desire data in below link

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/bpapxquaae9aa13/AADnan31ZASublDjN7sa2Vvza

I would like to know how can I modify one column of current and next record depending of some criteria using SQL Server 2012?

The criteria is:

```
Type should always flow F->T
if current abs(amount)> next abs(amount) then groupid = 'PD'
if current abs(amount)< next abs(amount) then groupid = 'PI'
there is no case when those amounts will be equals
where current(custid) = next(custid)  and current(service) = next(service)  and groupid is null
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Custid, service, and amount not found.  No definition of next.

Comment: original post has been updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custid, service, and amount not found. No definition of next.
This assumes next is based on ID

```
update table 
   set t1.groupid = 'PD', t1.type = 'f', t2.type = 't'
  from table t1  
  join table t2 
    on t2.id = t1.id + 1 
   and abs(t1.amount) > abs(t2.amount) 
   and t1.groupid  is null 
   and t1.cusid = t2.custid 
   and t2.service = t2.service 


update table 
   set t1.groupid = 'PI'
  from table t1  
  join table t2 
    on t2.id = t1.id + 1 
   and abs(t1.amount) < abs(t2.amount) 
   ...
```

Comment: that updated records that type = F, but I need below record that type is  = to T updated with same groupid as well, Thanks

Comment: set col1 = 'val1, col2 = 'val2'

Comment: could you please explain me that better? Thank you

Comment: Did you look at the update to my answer?  What is so hard about set more than one value using commas?